# Moment of Inertia of Square Lamina

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

I know how to compute this using an integral. However, I was told that I could derive this as well by placing 4 squares together of moment of inertia $$I=kmr^2$$ and derive it again but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If $I_1 = kmr^2$ about an axis through the centre and perpendicular to the plane then $I_4 = k(4m)(2r)^2$.

However you also know that from the parallel axis theorem the moment of inertia of one of the small squares about the axis perpendicular to the plane and though the centre of the big square is $kmr^2 + m\left( \frac {r}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2$.
So you can solve for $k$.